# How can i center a circle on an existing element in SVG (svg.js)?

Tags: svg, svg.js

Anyone who might be able to help out with this.
Please take a look at this Codepen:

https://codepen.io/mortennajbjerg/pen/zYrEMOe

I have tried this:

```
SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let canvas = SVG.get('australia-svg')

  let australia = canvas.select('[data-name="Australia"]')
  
  let pos = australia.rbox()

  let circle = canvas.circle(20)
    .fill('#900')
    .move(pos.x, pos.y)
})
```

I would like to center the circle in the middle of Australia, but I seem to be unable to do so? I am not allowed to change the existing SVG attributes in order to achieve the desired result.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Use pos.cx and pos.cy and center with the `center()` method instead of `move()`

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to help me find the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fuzzyma I came up with this solution. I am posting it here for reference.

````
SVG.on(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let canvas = SVG.get('australia-svg')

  let australia = canvas.select('[data-name="Australia"]').get(0)
  
  let pos = australia.rbox(canvas)
  
  let x = pos.cx - 10
  let y = pos.cy - 10

  let circle = canvas.circle(20)
    .fill('#900')
    .center(x, y)
})
```
````

Comment: Just make sure that rbox is what you actually want. It seemed to me that bbox is the method you should use

Comment: Good point. Rbox makes its calculations based on transformations too. Probably not needed in the example I posted. It was however needed on the site I was working on. For other users stumbling upon this bbox might be the better option.

Comment: In that case use rbox(canvas) to transform the coordinates into the canvas coordinate system. By default the coordinates are in screen coordinates and that's not what you want. It might even avoid the -10px for x and y

Comment: Exactly :) I struggled a lot before I figured that one out. I updated the example for future reference. Thanks again.